# Template is missing error - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My project has a list of books that users have added. Users can comment on added books. While commenting 'title' and 'content' are requested.

However, for these two properties in the `comment.rb` model

```rb
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :content, presence: true
```

I get this error when I add it. I don't get any errors when I remove these features.

```rb
Missing template comments/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}.
```

comments_controller.rb

```rb
def create
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @comment = @book.comments.new(comment_params)
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  @comment.status = "unapproved"
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to book_path(@book), notice: "Comment was successfully created."
  else
    render :new #It gives an error here
  end
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :content, :book_id, :status,:user_id)
end
```

comments.rb model

```rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
  scope :approved, -> { where status: 'approved'}
  scope :unapproved, -> { where status: 'unapproved'}
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Looks like while creating comment from some part of the app the validations are causing it to fail which might render comments/new again. Hence without the validations all would work well. Need to see more code to be sure though.

Comment: What are the params passed ? Is the file at app/views/comments/new.html.erb present ?

Comment: Please add the file tree of your app/views/comments directory to the question. There should be a new.html.erb file present.

Comment: No, I don't have a file named new.html.erb. I am doing the function of adding comments from the _form.html.erb file

Comment: Thank you. As you said, the error was fixed by creating the new.html.erb file.@AlokSwain @3DPrintScanner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is throwing an `Exception` as it is trying to render a file from the action and not finding it at the default paths it checks at for it.

Based on your code in controller, the file at `app/views/comments/new.html.erb` must be present so that the controller action can render it when the validation fails while creating the `comment` record.